# PowerManager.newWakeLock() throws IlleagelArgumentException

Tags: android

I am trying to aquire a wake lock however when I call `PowerManager.newWakeLock()` I receive a IlleglArgumentException.

Here is the code I use to get the

```
private void setWakeLock(Context context)
{
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    SoundAlarmActivity.WakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(
    PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "Alarm");
    SoundAlarmActivity.WakeLock.acquire();
}
```

And here is the logcat:

```
09-28 12:53:09.704: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(702): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
09-28 12:53:09.704: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(702):     at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.<init>(PowerManager.java:223)
09-28 12:53:09.704: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(702):     at android.os.PowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.java:365)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void setWakeLock(Context context)
{
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    SoundAlarmActivity.WakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(
    PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
        PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "BusSnoozeAlarm");
    SoundAlarmActivity.WakeLock.acquire();
}
```

PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP does not work with partial wake locks so you have to make sure you are using a FULL_WAKE_LOCK while defining the type of Wake Lock you want.

Comment: Thank you very very much, I've tried so many things and your solution works ;)

Comment: Isn't the full wake lock deprecated? How can I get the same behaviour without it?

Comment: I introduced ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP and got a runtime exception when creating the wakelock that ""Must specify a valid wake lock level". I added PARTIAL_WAKELOCK and it was accepted, despite what the docs say. It also seemed to work. Not 100% sure that it's working, as well as being accepted, but it seems that way. It's hard to force the situation where the wakelock is needed, to prove that it's actually working. So, use `PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK |
        PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE`

Answer (score 8):

You should define what "kind" of wake lock you want. The two flags you are giving are just additions to the level:

```
[WakeLock level] Flag Value | CPU | Screen | Keyboard
-----------------------------------------------------
PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK           | On* | Off    | Off
SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK        | On  | Dim    | Off
SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK     | On  | Bright | Off
FULL_WAKE_LOCK              | On  | Bright | Bright
```

Note: As of API level 17, except `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`, other wakelock levels are deprecated, instead you should use `LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`

Comment: Be aware that ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP will not work with a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK though.

Comment: So let me get this straight. The If ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP can't be used on its own because you should define what "kind" of wake lock you want, and if you don't, you get an exception stating "Must specify a valid wake lock level".  So you must choose one from the WakeLock level list. But, SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK and FULL_WAKE_LOCK are deprecated, and you say ok, I have one more remaining. And then... you realize that the only one that is not deprecated you can't use it with. So is there a correct way of doing this? FULL_WAKE_LOCK | ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP works just fine

Comment: I introduced ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP and got a runtime exception when creating the wakelock that ""Must specify a valid wake lock level". I added PARTIAL_WAKELOCK and it was accepted, despite what the docs say. It also seemed to work. Not 100% sure that it's working, as well as being accepted, but it seems that way. It's hard to force the situation where the wakelock is needed, to prove that it's actually working. So, use `PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK |
        PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE`

Comment: With a couple of days of testing and replicating the conditions which required the WakeLock I am confident that my solution above is working. I previously had just a PARTIAL_WAKELOCK which worked up till Android 9, but with Android 9 failed. The app is trying to start an activity from a service, where the phone may have been asleep for hours. With Android 9 the activity just wouldn't start. Adding AQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP and ON_AFTER_RELEASE to the PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK have got it working again.