# force close error on using wakelock

Tags: android, wakelock

i've searched a lot for an answer to my problem but nothing seems to be working. i'm using the ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP wakelock in my application. but whenever i run my code on the emulator as well as on the device, i get the force close error message.

My code is something like this:-

```
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    final PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
```

after checking for a condition, startAction() method is called. i need to acquire my wakelock inside this method.

```
    public void startAction(){  
        wakeLock.acquire();
        alert.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        click.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ....
    }
```

and on a stop button click event, i release my wakelock.

```
click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            v.cancel();
            tg.stopTone();
            tg.release();
            shouldRun=false;
            myThread.interrupt();
            message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
            message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            message.setText(body);                
            speakOut(); 
            wakeLock.release();


        }
```

logcat error shows:-

```
 02-25 13:05:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2026): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 13:05:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2026): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo  {com.example.accessinbox/com.example.accessinbox.AccessInbox}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
02-25 13:05:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-25 13:05:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-25 13:05:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-25 13:05:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-25 13:05:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-25 13:05:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-25 13:05:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-25 13:05:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 13:05:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-25 13:05:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-25 13:05:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-25 13:05:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 13:05:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2026): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
02-25 13:05:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.<init>(PowerManager.java:224)
02-25 13:05:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at android.os.PowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.java:396)
02-25 13:05:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at com.example.accessinbox.AccessInbox.onCreate(AccessInbox.java:63)
02-25 13:05:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-25 13:05:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-25 13:05:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812919/powermanager-newwakelock-trows-illeagelargumentexception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the kind of wakelock you want to aquire (read up on [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)), there's no default one, `PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP` is just an optional parameter.

You can see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/os/PowerManager.java#194) it ANDs the parameter with wakelock type mask and if there's nothing - throws you an IAE. They really should've put the exception message there, though, would have made this situation more clear.

Comment: Except for PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, all other wakelocks seem to be deprecated. any idea why is it so?

Comment: Well, it's mentioned in the corresponding descriptions - as of API17 they decided that you don't really need to use FULL_WAKE_LOCK or  unless you really know why you need to :) Mostly, people use it to get screen to not turn off, there's a flag for that to be combined with PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK. If you want a more in-depth explanation, you'll need to dig up API17 change log, maybe they have a more technical explanation.

In short, if you're sure you need, say SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK instead of PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK and WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON – don't mind the deprecation

Comment: thanks for the explanation :)   when i use the PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, it still shows the same error log. However, if i use the FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, it works fine. but is there a way to disable this flag once my task is done?

Comment: The flag will be active while your activity's up. So, to dismiss it, you can `.finish()` the activity if you don't need it any more or do `getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);` if you want the activity to remain there – in this case the screen will turn off after timeout as usual. Also, of course, don't forget to release the wake lock.